# Is it possible to find out which tabs are visible using Chrome DevTools?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I would like to use the [Chrome DevTools](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/1-3/Browser) to determine which tabs are currently **visible** to the user, that is, tabs that are activated on a non-minimized window. Note that for this use case, I consider windows that are not focused but that otherwise meet the previous criteria as visible.

I have been working through the DevTools API and using the [pychrome](https://fate0.github.io/pychrome/) library to inspect the state of my browser instance and its components. [Targets](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/1-3/Target) seem like the most relevant part of the API, however, when iterating over the different tabs, I find that for each tab there is always one target that is attached and that I am unable to discern whether or not that target is visible to the user. I have also tried executing the Javascript method `document.hasFocus()` but this returns false for visible windows that, well, don't have focus.

Is it possible to determine whether or not a tab in Chrome is visible using this API?

Comment: Use `document.visibilityState`

Comment: If you want to copy and paste that into an answer I would gladly accept it and award you with the free arbitary internet points that you deserve

Comment: It'd be better for posterity if you post an answer with a working fragment of your real code.